# How to load text in a input of type:text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website users can register, and after registering they can edit their information.

so I have a form like this:

```
<form name="edit-form" class="edit-form" action="php/edit_profile.php" method="post">
<div class="content">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"  class="input firstName"/>
</div></form>
```

Im trying to set the input text of "firstname" with jquery like this:

```
function edit_profile(fn)
{
var firstname = fn;
     $('.edit-form > .content >  input#firstName').text(firstname);
}
```

But it doesnt show anything in the field.
Dont worry about how I call the jquery function.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) sets the inner text of an element, and inner text is irrelevant in `<input>` elements.

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead:

```
$("#firstName").val("emad");
```

Answer (score 0):

for jquery just do it like this

```
<input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"  class="input firstName"/>
```

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#firstName").val("your value here");
```

if you want to put `emad` then

```
$('#firstName').val("emad");
```